# Как переместить запись из родительской таблицы в PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, наследование, postgresql9.6

У меня есть несколько таблиц с наследованием:

1. `product`
2. `smartphone`
3. `tablet`

Таблицы `smartphone` и `tablet` наследуются от `product`.
Допустим, я добавил запись в таблицу `smartphone`, но потом я хочу перенести эту запись в таблицу `tablet`. Мне нужно сохранить все внешние ключи, ID и набор полей. Это вообще возможно?

Comment: Напиши процедуру переноса, в которой обеспечь перемещение всех нужных данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось без проблем переместить запись с изменением типа из одной таблицы в другую. Если будете делать что то подобное, рекомендую обернуть конструкцию в транзакцию.

```
with deleted as (
  delete from only product.tablet 
  where id=12923
  returning *
)
insert into product.smartphone (id, created_at, updated_at, name, type, brand_id, additional_data, link)
select id, created_at, updated_at, name, 'smartphone', brand_id, additional_data, link
from deleted;
```